# jQuery - document.ready not firing when content loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple custom tabbing module, that loads tabs with an AJAX request (via `$(elem).load()`). On each page that is loaded with AJAX I have some JavaScript. The first time the page loads (via direct input of URL, not AJAX), the javascript fires up perfectly. When I navigate away from the page via the AJAX tabs, the javascripts from the pages aren't loading anymore.

Is there any way I can force them to execute?

(The javascript that is not firing is placed in a `$(document).ready()` function if that helps)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use callback of [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function:

```
$(elem).load('source.html', function() { 
    // here you need to perofrm something what you need
    ActionOnDocumentReady();
});
```

You can put all your actions in `$(document).ready` into some function (ex `ActionOnDocumentReady()`) and call it on [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) callback.

Comment: How to do this when programming on a third party platform where we have no control on the load function.

Comment: It really depends on the platform and what is available for you. Usually, you should have some sort of events/callbacks that is triggered when content is loaded from ajax call. That would be your best place to initiate the part of the code you need.

Answer (score 5):

the domeready event fires only when is initial dom is ready (like the name and the [jquery-api](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) suggest).

if you want to use jquerys load() and fire a function if that loading has been done, you'll have to use a callback-function ([according to the api](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)).

if you want to do the same thing on domready and load-events, the best way would be to define a new function for that:

```
function dostuff(){
  // do some stuff here
}
```

and fire this function in both cases:

```
$(function(){  // domready | shortcut for "$(document).ready()"
  dostuff();
})

$('#something').load('script.php', function() { // callback on load()
  dostuff();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your `$(document).ready()` code in a new method. Lets call it `methodA`. Now call this `methodA` from `$(document).ready()`. Secondly, call the same method after ajax request is successful. That should solve your problem.