# jQuery code works only once in wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a custom wordpress theme and have added a bit of `jQuery` to add a little pazazz to the site. The code works like a dream, but only when the page loads... When clicking through the menu and then returning tho said page, the `jQuery` will not run again.

I have used `wp_enqueue_script` in my `functions.php` and tried several solutions given to similar questions, but nothing works for me.

Here is an example code snippet which I use to check whether it works (which it doesn't).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("#content-djur img").load(function(){

        alert("test");      

        });
});
```

The framework of the code is the same, the content a bit different, but also here pops the alert box only up when initially loading the page, not after coming to it from another.

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this, and maybe more important on WHY this happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498220/jquery-document-ready-not-firing-when-content-loaded-with-ajax

Comment: Read this. I can also recommend the imagesLoaded plugin that they suggest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185390/proper-jquery-image-load/11185589#11185589

Comment: @ClaytonLies, I would not have thought to fix it like that, nor would I have thought to search the problem with the image load, but it worked!Thanks a million!